# Keeping an object over the lifetime of a request in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to create an object at the beginning of the handling of a request and keep it associated during the whole life time of the request. In the context of a request it should behave like a singleton, so each request gets one and not more than one of them.

Now I'm thinking I could make it attach itself to the `request` variable in it's `__new__` method, that would work, but I'm unsure if there isn't a nicer way to do this than to clutter the `request` variable?

```
class AuthScheme(object):
    context_attribute = 'auth_scheme'

    # inside the context of a request behave like a singleton
    def __new__(cls, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(request, cls.context_attribute):
            # instantiante via base class only if there is no instance
            # for this request yet
            instance = super(AuthScheme, cls).__new__(
                cls, request, *args, **kwargs)
            setattr(request, cls.context_attribute, instance)

        # return instance from request context
        return getattr(request, cls.context_attribute)
```

I'm also worried about collisions if something else would try to create a property of the `request` object with the same name. Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: Why not use a session?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks for the tip, but according to my understanding sessions are used to keep values across multiple requests, no? I only want to keep this object for the time of a single request.

Comment: You are saying "whole lifetime of a request", a request is finished when the page is served to the browser. Are you sure you are looking at the right place? Is there a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @dirn thanks, didn't know this one, it seems to be what I'm looking for! If you write an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The problem is that I need to create this object in the beginning of the request handling. Later I'll need to retrieve it again in an `after_request` decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#application-globals) is what you are looking for.

```
from flask import g
```

You can add any attributes you want to `g`. It's created anew for each request. [One common use is for storing a reference to the database](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/dbcon/#tutorial-dbcon).

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```